# Is synchronization required?

Tags: go, goroutine

I defined a variable (r.something) inside an object

```
func (r *Runner) init() {
  r.something = make(map[string]int)
  r.something["a"]=1

  go r.goroutine()
}
```

while r.goroutine uses value stored in r.something with no synchronization.
Nobody else is going to read/write this value except r.goroutine()

Is it safe to do without synchronization?

In other words: I want to reuse some variable from a goroutine initialized somewhere else *before* goroutine start. Is that safe?

Additional question:
After r.goroutine() finishes I want to be able to use r.something from somewhere else(without read/write overlap with other goroutines). Is it safe too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course this is safe, otherwise programming in Go might be a nightmare (or at least much less pleasant). [The Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem) is an interesting piece to read.

The routine creation is a synchronisation point. There is an example very similar to yours:

```
var a string

func f() {
    print(a)
}

func hello() {
    a = "hello, world"
    go f()
}
```

With the following comment:

> calling hello will print "hello, world" at some point in the future (perhaps after hello has returned).

This is because:

> The go statement that starts a new goroutine happens **before** the goroutine's execution begins.

The word *before* is crucial here as it implies routine creation (in one thread) must be synchronised with its start (possibly in other thread), so writes to *a* must be visible by the new routine.

Comment: Totally makes sense! Thanks @tomasz

Answer (score 3):

If there is no situation where an **overlap** of **read and write** operations by different go-routines may occur on this variable, then you are right: there is no need for any synchonization.

As you have mentioned that the variable was initialized **before** your go-routine started, you are in fact safe.

Comment: What about the fact that variables modified in one OS-thread may not be visible from another OS-thread unless access is wrapped into explicit synchronization like sync.Mutex. I know we're talking about goroutines but under the hood it goes down to OS-threads, though not always. How does it relate with the variable initialization before goroutine start, does golang perform implicit synchronization of captured variables somewhere inside before goroutine start?

Comment: We need to be precise about the term "visible" here: Of course a variable is visible (as in: visible at all) for every thread of a given process. The problem is: Is a **change** made by thread A visible to thread B **on time**. This may not be the case, if the two threads are accessing the variable **concurrently**. But as the first thread (I use this synonymously for go-routines: the two behave very much alike) has long finished it's modifications before the second one even existed, we are safe. There is no implicit synchronization by the go runtime, the implicit sync is done by your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe. According to [Go Memory Model](http://golang.org/ref/mem):

- the go statement that starts a new goroutine happens before the goroutine's execution begins
- within a single goroutine, the happens-before order is the order expressed by the program

This means that all changes to variables that you made before starting a goroutine are visible inside this goroutine.

Answer to your additional question: it depends. Generally if `r.goroutine()` modified `r.something` and you want to read it from another goroutine you need to use synchronisation.